# Alternating power sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-towers

I quite randomly stumbled upon the following phenomenon:

Let $ f:\mathbb R^+\to\mathbb R^+, x\mapsto x^{-2^{3^{-4^{\cdot^{\cdot^{\cdot}}}}}} $, then in the interval of $[1,20)$ the plot of $f$ looks like the following:

[image: plot of f]

This looks surprisingly similar to the plot of $\frac{1}{x}$, plotted in red:

[image: plot of f and 1/x]

Why is that? And why is $f$ even well defined (i.e. why does the sequence converge)? It seems as if there exists some $\xi\in[1,2]$ for which
$$\forall x\in\mathbb R^+:f(x)=x^{-\xi}\qquad\xi\simeq 1.2$$

$f$ is undefined for negative values and diverges at $0$:
$$\lim\limits_{x\searrow0}f(x)\to\infty $$

Can anyone explain those properties / link to some proof? I'd be quite curious about the exact value of $\xi$ too.

Also, if you're interested or don't trust me, I've created the plots with [this](https://gist.github.com/bbc3e89c0939eb75044918ac07a40f6e) program.

---

So to clarify this a bit, the problem can be formulated the following way:

Show that
$$\xi:=-\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}-2^{3^{-4^{\cdot^{\cdot^{\cdot^{\sigma(n)\cdot n}}}}}}\simeq1.1982330602188767$$
$$\sigma:\mathbb N\to\{-1,1\},\ n\mapsto\begin{cases}-1& n\mod2=0\\1&n\mod2=1\end{cases}$$

---

We can formulate this mathematically precisely:

Let $\sigma$ be as defined previously, then define
$$e:\mathbb N^2\to\mathbb R,\ (m,n)\mapsto\begin{cases}\sigma(m)\cdot m^{e(m+1,n)}&m<n\\\sigma(m)\cdot m&m=n\end{cases}$$

then $\xi$ is defined as
$$\xi:=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}e(2,n)$$

For this we can proof that $\xi\in(-2,-1)$ by something like the following:
$$\forall n\in\mathbb N:\ e(4,n)=-4^{r(n)}\quad r(n)>0\implies e(4,n)<-1$$
$$\implies e(3,n)=3^{e(4,n)}=\left|3^{e(4,n)}\right|<1$$
$$\implies e(2,n)=-2^{e(3,n)}\in(-2,-1)$$

However, this is not a full proof of convergence (but merely of limitedness). I feel like the proof of convergence should contain the value it converges to. But if the value of $\xi$ only appears by this construction, that's rather difficult.

It would also suffice to proof the monotony of $e(2,\cdot)$ - however, it clearly isn't monotonous.

Maybe, similarly to the proof I presented, the interval for $\xi$ can be minimized bit by bit, but I don't quite know how I'd proceed there.

---

The above proof can easily be generified to the following ($\forall n\in\mathbb N$):
$$\forall m\in 2\mathbb N:\ e(m,n)<-1$$
$$\implies\forall o\in\mathbb N\setminus2\mathbb N:\ e(o,n)=|e(o,n)|<1$$
$$\implies\forall p\in2\mathbb N:\ e(p,n)\in(-m,-1)$$

However, a quick computer program indicates that
$$\forall m\in2\mathbb N,\ n\gg m:\ e(m,n)\in(-2,-1)$$
I don't know if that's of any use though.

Comment: @PeterForeman this is quite true, though it doesn't explain why $f$ is undefined for negative values.

Comment: @PeterForeman As $-(1^{1.2})=-1$, or more generally as $-\frac{1}{x^{1.2}}$. I was under the impression that the exponentiation is well defined for negative numbers.

Comment: That's not how exponentiation works...

Comment: Some Python code gives the more accurate value$$\xi\approx1.1982330602188767$$

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt you're right, my bad.

Comment: It looks like $1/x$ because the exponent $-1.00859409158$ is close to $-1$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I doubt the exponent is $-1.0086$ - this curve is very much different from the curve I got. Peters estimate of $1.198$ seemed much more reasonable. It would be interesting though if this number is in connection with another famous irrational number, like $e$, and of course why so.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I vouch for the value obtained by Peter. I doubt this has a closed form or any "connection" to something like $e$.

Comment: " I doubt the exponent is −1.0086 ": well, this is a silly thing to have "doubts" about. print -(2.0)**((3.0)**(-4))

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I'm not sure what you mean by "the value obtained by Peterr". Above I see a Peter saying something about the value of $\xi$, but I don't see any indication of what we _mean_ here by $\xi$; maybe the definition was in a deleted comment? In an case, regardless of what you do or do not vouch for, -(2.0)**((3.0)**(-4))=1.00859

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich the definition of $\xi$ is in the question itself. And it's an infinite sequence, not just until $-4$ - that's why there are dots.

Comment: There is no point studying the behavior of $f$ vs. that of $1/x$. $f$ is clearly $x$ to some power and it is enough to study that power (vs. $-1$).

Comment: @YvesDaoust that's why I added the clarification.

Comment: It's not even clear how you define the infinite power. How is it defined?

Comment: @Allawonder OP defines it by the limit $\xi:=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}e(2,n),$ which can be shown to exist via the monotone convergence theorem. (See my answer.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $t_n=e(2,n)$; i.e., $t_2=-2, t_3=-2^{3}, t_4=-2^{3^{-4}}, t_5=-2^{3^{-4^5}}, t_6=-2^{3^{-4^{5^{-6}}}}$, etc. Now, although the sequence $(t_n)_n$ is not monotone, it is composed of the following four monotone subsequences:
$$\begin{align}
&t_2<t_6<t_{10}<t_{14}<\cdots\tag{A}\\
&t_3<t_7<t_{11}<t_{15}<\cdots\tag{B}\\
&t_4>t_8>t_{12}>t_{16}>\cdots\tag{C}\\
&t_5>t_9>t_{13}>t_{17}>\cdots\tag{D}
\end{align}$$

(A)-(D) are straightforward (but tedious) to prove by comparing the towers $t_n$ and $t_{n+4}$; similarly, it can be shown that for all $n\ge 6$,
$$ \min(t_{n-4},t_{n-1})<t_n<\max(t_{n-4},t_{n-1}).\tag{E}
$$
Since $-8\le t_n< -1$ the monotone convergence theorem gives that all four of the subsequences converge, and by (E) they all converge to the same limit. Computations (in Sage) show this to be $\xi=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}t_n=-1.198233060218876592050411767\dots$

Here are some pictures:

[image: convergent subsequences and the convergent sequence]

---

**Aside**:

We can extend the OP's domain of definition of $e(m,n)$ to $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ and define 
$$\xi_m:=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}e(m,n).$$
Then the doubly-infinite sequence $$(\ldots,\xi_{-2},\xi_{-1},\xi_{0},\xi_{1},\xi_{2},\ldots)$$
is well-defined and satisfies the recursion
$$\xi_m=\sigma(m)\,m^{\xi_{m+1}}$$
where $\sigma(m) = -1 \text{ if $m$ is even, else $+1$ if $m$ is odd}.$

In particular, we find 
$$\begin{align}
\vdots\\
\xi_{-p}&= p^{{(p-1)}^{  {(p-2)}^{.^{{.^{.}}^1}}}  }, p\ge 1\\
\vdots\\
\xi_{-4}&=4^{3^{2^1}}\\
\xi_{-3}&=3^{2^1}\\
\xi_{-2}&=2^1\\
\xi_{-1}&=1\\
\xi_0&=0\\
\xi_1&=1\\
\xi_2&=-2^{3^{{-4}^{5^{.^{.^.}}}}}=−1.198233060218876592050411767\ldots\\
\xi_3&=\log_2(-\xi_2)=0.260908544287382650344471086\ldots\\
\xi_4&=\log_3(\xi_3)=-1.222984079054583379571125508\ldots\\
\xi_5&=\log_4(-\xi_4)=0.145202811409957592071338045\ldots\\
\xi_6&=\log_5(\xi_5)=-1.198942686476802521519469705\ldots\\
\xi_7&=\log_6(-\xi_6)=0.101263633269622829392559457\ldots\\
\xi_8&=\log_7(\xi_7)=-1.176841558483650376687654327\ldots\\
\vdots\\
\end{align}$$
and
$$\begin{align}\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\xi_{2k}&=-1\tag{F}\\
\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\xi_{2k-1}&=0.\tag{G}\end{align}
$$

Here are some pictures:

[image]

(The SageMath code that I used is available [here](https://gist.github.com/r-e-s-0001/43f0ab41356873bdc4858ed188f0872c).)

Comment: It seems to me as if this is a pretty fascinating phenomenon. Do you know of any resource handling it? Are there any papers about it?

Comment: @MetaColon - I haven't seen any discussion about this, except for the "[exponential factorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_factorial)" $(m\$ )$ that show up 
in $(\xi_m)_{m< 0}$ (i.e., $\xi_{-m}=m\$:=m^{{(m-1)}^{  {(m-2)}^{.^{{.^{.}}^1}}}  },\ m>0$).